# Order of running two consecutive appscripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there any reason why two scripts in the same function is working in one order and not in another order? I have two functions, when I run FolderLists first then FolderMaker runs after but if I run FolderMaker first then Folder list is not running.

```
function Button(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() === 'answers') {

      FolderMaker();
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      Utilities.sleep(3000)
      FolderList();

}
}

function FolderMaker(){
      createFoldersTasks_();
      createFolderByTask_();
      createFolders_();
      createFolderInFolder_();
      isFolderInFolder_();
}

function FolderList(){
      listFolers();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean to say, is it like when you are calling like this:`

```html
function Button(e) {
      FolderMaker();
      FolderList();
}
```

It is working correctly, but when you try this:

```html
function Button(e) {
      FolderList();
      FolderMaker();
}
```

It is not working,I will suggest you that you can try debugging using msgbox or adding breakpoints, try this code it will show a message box in the google sheet if you edit the sheet named "answers"

```html
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() === 'answers') {
      FolderMaker();
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      Utilities.sleep(300)
      FolderList();

}
}

function FolderMaker(){
      Browser.msgBox('called FolderMaker');
}

function FolderList(){
      Browser.msgBox('called FolderList');
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

### There is no reason for it, the order should not matter

- If the second function does not run, most likely some of the functions called by the first function resulted in an error that stopped the further script execution. Please check your `executions`.

- Alternatively, the script stopped executing, because it surpassed the [maximum quota limit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) for `Script runtime` or even `Triggers total runtime`

In any case, since both fo your funciton run other functions, you can merge them into one:

```js
function Button(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() === 'answers') {

      FolderMaker();
  }
}

function FolderMaker(){
      createFoldersTasks_();
      createFolderByTask_();
      createFolders_();
      createFolderInFolder_();
      isFolderInFolder_();
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      Utilities.sleep(3000);
      listFolers();
}
```

Side note:

Is it correct that your function is called `listFolers()` and not `listFolders()`?

UPDATE

- Make sure that within the collection of projects bound to your spreadsheet you not have any duplicates of function names and triggers.

---

[image]

---

Comment: Thanks, I ran the functions both ways combined and I get the same result, with the FolderMaker first it works, with the listFolers (misspelling on my part) it doesn't work. Scratching my head a bit still, it should not have anything to do with quotas.

Comment: Can you see any erros in the executions? Otherwise, can you share a sample spreadsheet for reproduction?

Comment: I can see your problem now! Your spreadsheet contains two scripts! `LJJ Add company` and `SWN add company` and both scripts have functions with the same names. Since both scripts belong to the same spreadsheet, it's the same as if they were in the same script file and the trigger does not know which function to run. Either delete the script file you are not using, or comment out or rename the functions of this script. And make sure to have only one onEdit trigger.

Comment: I deleted LJJ Add Company. And unfortunately the same  issue, listFolers is still not firing and it is ony one trigger. :(

Comment: I see that you two installe onEdit triggers. Can you go to your triggers, delete them all and then install only one trigger (call all necessar functions from one only triggered function)

Comment: I laos jsut noticed that you have two functions called  "listFolers()" in the remaining script project! Same here - avoid all duplicates, no matter in which script file of the project the functions are contained. And btw., what makes you think the funciton does not run? Try to implement a log in the (remaining) function.